# Create a local version of my website

Tags: joomla-3.x

I'm having a Joomla website and I'd like to download it and and set it up locally on my pc. So, I'm having a general idea of how I should do it: Download XAMPP and set it up, backup my joomla website and upload the backup on the xampp's htdocs folder. The problem is how i integrate the website's database with the local version of the website i have set up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This task is actually pretty easy.

- Install Akeeba Backup
- create a backup. This includes files and database
- download Akeeba Kickstart
- use Kickstart to install the backup on your local environment

https://www.akeebabackup.com/products/akeeba-backup.html
https://www.akeebabackup.com/products/akeeba-kickstart.html

When it comes to a local environment I use vagrant. It creates a virtual machine and makes fiddling around with a Windows unnecessary. Also you can always reset it. No old data, always a dedicated fresh environment.